# imagewebp не принимает путь на кириллице?

Tags: php

Пишу скрипт по конвертации изображений в .webp. Скрипт конвертирует и кладет рядом с оригиналом изображение в webp. Однако если папка содержит кириллицу, то функция imagewebp не выполняется. Вот код, в чем проблема? спасибо.

```
function ConvertToWebp($dir) /*В аргумент передаем абсолютный путь каталога*/
{

$absolutDir=$dir;
$results = scandir($absolutDir);/*Возвращает массив с содержанием каталога*/

foreach ($results as $value) {
    if ($value=='.' || $value=='..') {/*игнорируем навигационные символы, которые возвращает scandir*/
        continue;
    }

    if (is_file($absolutDir.$value)) {
        $image=$absolutDir.$value;/*Получаем абсолютную ссылку на файл*/
        $arg=mb_strtolower(substr(strrchr($image, '.'), 1));/*получаем расширение файла в нижнем регистре*/
        if ($arg=='jpg' || $arg=='jpeg') {
            $im=imagecreatefromjpeg($image);/*создает изображение в jpg из файла по ссылке, типо шаблона наверное*/ 
            $infoImage=pathinfo($image);/*атрибуты файла*/
            $nameImage=$infoImage['filename'];/*имя файла без расширения*/
            $absoluteDirForImage=$infoImage['dirname'].'/';/*абсолютная ссылка до файла*/
            $webp=imagewebp($im, $absoluteDirForImage.$nameImage.'.webp');/*конвертация созданного изображения. <абсолютная ссылка до файла><имя файла без расширения><и добавляем расширение .webp>*/
            imagedestroy($im);/*удаляем шаблон изображения*/        
        }
         if ($arg=='png') {
            $im=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
            $infoImage=pathinfo($image);
            $nameImage=$infoImage['filename'];
            $absoluteDirForImage=$infoImage['dirname'].'/';
            $webp=imagewebp($im, $absoluteDirForImage.$nameImage.'.webp');
            imagedestroy($im);      
         }
    }

      if (is_dir($absolutDir.$value)) {
         $dir=pathinfo($absolutDir.$value);
         ConvertToWebp($dir['dirname'].'/'.$dir['filename'].'/');
      }
}
/*profit*/
}

echo ConvertToWebp('/images/testwebp/ппп/');
```

Comment: следует использовать `mb_substr` вместо `substr`

Comment: Спасибо, но нет, не работает.

Comment: 1. Откройте для себя [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.directoryiterator.php), что избавит вас от лишних действий в этом коде. 2. Тип файла `JPEG/PNG/etc` следует определять по [MIME-типу](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php). Может быть потому что MIME тип не соответствует расширению?

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал определять расширение функцией mime_content_type() , но увы, результат остался прежним.
    $arg=mime_content_type($image);
    if ($arg=='image/jpeg') { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за подсказки.
Я не понял что произошло, но код начал выполняться по всем папкам, вне зависимости от названия. Саморазрешаемая проблема. Возможно при тестировании что-то напутал с правами на каталог. Ниже рабочий код после небольшого рефакторинга.

```
function ConvertToWebp($dir) /*В аргумент передаем абсолютный путь каталога*/
{

$absolutDir=$dir;
$results = scandir($absolutDir);/*Возвращает массив с содержанием каталога*/

foreach ($results as $value) {
    if ($value=='.' || $value=='..') {/*игнорируем навигационные символы, которые возвращает scandir*/
        continue;
    }

    if (is_file($absolutDir.'/'.$value)) {
        $image=$absolutDir.'/'.$value;/*Получаем абсолютную ссылку на файл*/
        $arg=mime_content_type($image);/*получаем расширение файла в нижнем регистре*/
        if ($arg=='image/jpeg') {
            $im=imagecreatefromjpeg($image);/*создает изображение из файла по ссылке*/ 
       }
       if ($arg=='image/png') {
          $im=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
       }
       $infoImage=pathinfo($image);/*атрибуты файла*/
       $nameImage=$infoImage['filename'];/*имя файла без расширения*/
       $absoluteDirForImage=$infoImage['dirname'].'/';/*абсолютная ссылка до файла*/
       $webp=imagewebp($im, 
       $absoluteDirForImage.$nameImage.'.webp');/*конвертация созданного изображения. <абсолютная ссылка до файла><имя файла без расширения><и добавляем расширение .webp>*/
       imagedestroy($im);/*удаляем шаблон изображения*/        
       }

      if (is_dir($absolutDir.'/'.$value)) {
         $dir=pathinfo($absolutDir.'/'.$value);
         ConvertToWebp($dir['dirname'].'/'.$dir['filename'].'/');
      }
}
/*profit*/
}
echo ConvertToWebp('/frontend/web/images/testwebp');
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Apache - это нормально, так как он не умеет работать с названиями файлов/директорий на кириллице. Можете протестировать взяв basename файла название которого на кириллице через скрипт php и получите кракозябры. Просто этому багу как я понимаю много лет => в сети начали появлятся самописные скрипты для взятия названий файлов, но на моем личном опыте - они не работают. Вывод таков - апач не любит кириллицу, так что ищите какие-либо скрипты на замену тем функциям для работы с названиями файлов/директорий в интернете (Если вы используете не apache, то я без понятия).

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня не Apache, у меня Nginx v.1.10.3 )